# find word with dollar sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I trying to find words with the first character ($) using regex but I couldn't make it to work.
I tried:

```
$string = '$David is the cool, but $John is not cool.';
preg_match('/\b($\w+)\b/', $string, $matches);
```

I tried to escape the $ but still doesn't work:

```
preg_match('/\b(\$\w+)\b/', $string, $matches);
```

I'd like to extract [$David, $John] .

Please help!

Comment: $ is a metacharacter that needs to be escaped when it's a literal.

Comment: I've tried to escape but it still doesn't work: preg_match('/\b(\$\w+)\b/', $string, $matches);

Comment: Now that you've escaped it you need a `\B` to it's left. So, the new regex is `(?:\B|^)(\$\w+)\b`

Comment: preg_match('(?:\B|^)(\$\w+)\b', $string, $matches);  Doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure you have to take care of what is around your target, whatever using a word boundary at the end is useless.

Comment: `(?:\B|^)` is redundant, `\B` does the same.

Comment: It works at regex101, but doesn't work with my PHP, here is the simple php code: $string = '$David is the cool, but $John is not cool.';
preg_match('(?:\B|^)(\$\w+)\b', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);

Comment: preg_match_all('(?:\B|^)(\$\w+)\b', $string, $matches); Doesn't work either

Comment: Use simply `preg_match_all('/(\$\w+)/', $string, $matches);`

Comment: @VictorHugo - your code errors because you're missing a regex delimiter. Use this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/874bd988d47efc3720330e4e3240dd05945366a3

Comment: Thanks sln, that works :-)

Comment: Where `matches[1]` is the array of group 1 matches, or you could take out the parenthesis, then use matches[0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` won't match between a non-word character and `$` (another non-word character).

```
\b
```

is equivalent to

```
(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)
```

so you could use

```
/(?<!\w)(\$\w+)\b/
```

That said, there's probably no reason to check what's before the `$`, so the following should do:

```
/(\$\w+)\b/
```

Additionally, that `\b` will always match, so it can be left out.

```
/(\$\w+)/
```

---

Additionally, you appear to want all matches. For that, you'll need to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`.

Comment: I use /(\$\w+)/ and it returns : Array ( [0] => $David [1] => $David ) -------- it misses $John

Comment: To get all matches, you need `preg_match_all`. Added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, there're no needs to use word boundary and non word boundary, but to match oth variables, you have to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$string = '$David is the cool, but $John is not cool.';
preg_match_all('/(\$\w+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $David
            [1] => $John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => $David
            [1] => $John
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi Toto, why duplicate array ?

Comment: preg_match_all('/(\$\w+)\b/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); returns -------------- Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $David
            [1] => $David
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => $John
            [1] => $John
        )

)

Comment: The first array matches the whole match and second is the content of the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks alot  toto.